# Solo Mining with ether-proxy

Tags: ether

I am trying to solo-mine.  I am using geth and ethminer on windows.

I recently added ether-proxy so that I can see progress.

However, ether-proxy now thinks that I am part of a pool and its forcing me to set a difficulty.  I am guessing it is asking what difficulty do I want to solve.  Since shares do not matter to solo mining, does anyone know what difficulty I should set in Ether-Proxy so that my node tries to solve a full block?  There is zero documentation.  According to the author, the fields are self-described.

To make matters more confusing, Ether-proxy is also reporting that the network difficulty is Difficulty: 79,764,482,404,251

Since ether-proxy is forcing me to enter a difficulty, I put it in 500.  Which its reporting as 50000000000.

2017/12/18 13:36:55 Valid share at height 2427590/2427590 from R01@192.168.1.248 at difficulty 50000000000

My question is, does anyone know what difficulty do I need to set so that my node tries to resolve the entire block and not just a share?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my knowledge eth-proxy is only used for mining against a mining pool using Stratum proxy.  I use it to point to DwarfPool as my 6 GPUS would not mine anything on their own solo.

If you are solo mining and not using a pool just download geth and let it sync then run ethminer.  I did a walkthrough of Mining ethereum on AWS GPU's the same steps should be relevant for you.  Take a look and see does it help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUQ9UW6f5Dg&t=1s